# Virtualization - Linux host - running Adobe After Effects with hardware acceleration (using OpenGL)?

Tags: virtualbox, virtual-machine, qemu, gpu

### Introduction

Thinking about a laptop for graphic work, using After Effects (and other Adobe software). As there is to use those proprietary software (we are aware of open source alternatives like the great [Natron](https://natrongithub.github.io/)), the choice is either:

- Windows
- Mac OS

Unfortunately, Adobe does not work in Linux. As I'd never recommend to anybody to use Windows as a primary OS, the 2 remaining choices are:

- Mac OS
- Windows under Linux with virtualisation

### Question

I used Vegas video edition soft under Linux using Virtualbox without any problems; using Intel VT-x acceleration, but this is for CPU access.

I wonder if OpenGL is a suitable technology for GPU access in Windows under Linux host ? (using Qemu or Virtualbox (VMware or ?))

Has anybody experienced this configuration ?

In that case, we'll buy a powerful PC laptop with a good GPU and a CPU offering Intel VT-x, but if this is not a "good idea" we'll buy a Mac laptop.

Comment: If you have money, buy the Mac. Linux needs a lot of babysitting and many things can go work with the GPU pass trough. On top of that, the top tier VmWare workstation licenses are *expensive*.